# setValues on the first empty row in a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a script that will take a table with student's names and their first, second, and so on choices for an activity and then put them into a class roster by grade. I have got everything working in my test except that it won't setValues next to each other. I know this is because of the .getLastRow that I am using but I can't think of any other way. Secondly, I am forced to use separate for loops or it will just place the names wherever in the loop it finds them and makes a mess.

Here is my code:

```
function StreamRoster2() {

  var grade = 2;
  var name = 1;
  var choice1 = 3;
  var fifth = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1prA4_1z_8JGsjKHGLOQKj0FCo1pF7tDCxdR_nHkBqq8").getSheetByName("Fifth");

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1prA4_1z_8JGsjKHGLOQKj0FCo1pF7tDCxdR_nHkBqq8").getSheetByName("Results").getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {  
    if (data[i][grade] === 'Fifth' && data[i][choice1] === 1) {
       fifth.getRange(fifth.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(data[i][name]);
    } 
  } 

  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {  
    if (data[i][grade] === 'Fifth' && data[i][choice1] === 2) {
       fifth.getRange(fifth.getLastRow()+1, 2).setValue(data[i][name]);
     }     
    } 
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {  
    if (data[i][grade] === 'Fifth' && data[i][choice1] === 3) {
        fifth.getRange(fifth.getLastRow()+1, 3).setValue(data[i][name]);
     }     
    } 

   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   Browser.msgBox("Classes Created");  
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
[What it looks like in the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VSOI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter and only increment it if there is a match:

```
var foundCounter = 0;

for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {  
  if (data[i][grade] === 'Fifth' && data[i][choice1] === 1) {
    foundCounter +=1;
    fifth.getRange(foundCounter, 1).setValue(data[i][name]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Good news was it was a super fast script. Bad news it placed the values in the same row it found them in from the source table. Thanks!!! But I really need them to start at row 1 and then fill the sequential rows. I plan to put in a pdf blob to make it easy for the teachers to organize the class so I was hoping to not have a lot of blank spaces. I could manually copy paste to line everything up, but I always think there has to be a way to code it.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Consider marking the answer as correct it it worked for you.